# Package installation - Outdated repository

Tags: miktex, repositories

all

Today, when I wanted to install some packages from MikTeX 2.9, I found that I cannot do so with the error:

> The remote package repository is outdated.

I have tried several repositories already and they all gave the same problem. I have tried to re-download the MikTeX and checked. The problem still arose. What can I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 5):

There were problems with MiKTeX yesterday. In fact even the [MiKTeX website](https://miktex.org/) wasn't accessible. I have the same problem as you, but I believe that it will be solved in a few hours.

Comment: See also https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/49 & https://miktex.org/alert/miktex-6582-out-of-sync